# JqPlot  not displaying graphs on devices sometimes

Tags: android, jqplot

I am developing a web application for mobile devices including tabs.
I am using JqPlot for displaying graphs every thing works fine on my desktops and emulators 
But it **not displaying graphs on devices sometimes**.
Even chart values are displayed but graph is not get drawn 
Any suggestions and answers are welcome ..
 please help us.... 
Also Want To know do there is any way to debug on device browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you have assigned the DIV id to the function and you need to create the DOM div elements before calling the chart plugin,
if this **works on emulators and not in actual devices means it can have memory leaks**,
 if you are re drawing the chart make sure the previous objects are disposed..I'm just suggesting something and that's all

Comment: Thanks for the answer ... We are re drawing the chart Do you can suggest some good  ways to dispose the previous objects ..

Comment: just check the reference for null and if yes call the function or if not destroy the previous java script object